# Error for library not referenced in class

Tags: java

Short code snip to get a folder / file listing:

```
        GetFilesFolders gf = new GetFilesFolders();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> adOn = gf.getFileListing(pth1, true);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> orIg = gf.getFileListing(pth2, true);

        List<String> Conflict_Addons = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> Conflict_Orig = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String i : adOn){
            for(String r : orIg){
                java.io.File ad = new java.io.File(i);
                java.io.File or = new java.io.File(r);
                if(ad.getName().equals(or.getName())){
                    Conflict_Addons.add(i);
                    Conflict_Orig.add(r);
                }
            }
        }
```

The error that I am getting when run is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javaxt.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.String

    at modmaker.Merger$$Lambda$49/826640700.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1235)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at modmaker.Merger.checkConflicts(Merger.java:206)
```

206 is:  for(String i : adOn){

I am using javaxt in the project but not in this class or the GetFilesFolders class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having some kind of issue in `gf.getFileListing(pth1, true)`. You can use debugger to check that the returned `List` have instances of `String` inside. Looks like somebody is lying to you and giving you a List of Files and saying is a List of Strings.

Comment: Been a long night, in getFileListing  I am in fact using :
files = directory.getChildren (recurse, "*.*", true); which is returning a List of Files, surprised that the adOn and orIg Lists aren't complaining more. Thanks for the wakeup smack.